# select all of the messages in a conversation in mail.app

Tags: macos, email, apple-mail

When you select an email in mail.app it will highlight all of the other emails in the same conversation in light blue color.  Is it possible to somehow tell mail.app to select all of these messages so that I can delete them or move them to a different folder?

Thanks,

josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you in *Organize by thread* mode (View menu)? When viewing messages in thread mode, selecting the top level of a given thread will select all the messages. If you're viewing one message within the tread, pressing ← will close the tread and keep it selected, which includes all the contained messages.

[image]

(I snagged the above picture from [here](http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/06/01/gmail-vs-mailapp/).)

Answer (score 2):

There's a menu item *View » Select » All Messages in this Thread* with the keyboard shortcut `Command-Shift-K`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click on the first message.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click on the last message in the thread.
3. <kbd>Command</kbd> + click and delete.